# Tighten hinge on 27" Cinema Display?

Tags: cinema-display

I just purchased a new 27" Cinema Display from Apple and I'm wondering if there is any way to tighten the hinge that attaches to the stand for adjusting the angle. I'm a DJ and noticed when I'm performing, the display keeps tilting forward on it's own (likely from some slight bass vibrations). I have two 24" Cinema Displays and the hinge has much more friction than the 27" - I realize the size and weight is greater, although are they normally so loosey goosey?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods to do that.

1- Mechanical

2-Chemical

- for mechanical take the screw out and bring it to your hardware store, they will give you tongued washers or claw washers that prevents the screw from loosening.

The pro for this method is you can loosen the screw.

- for Chemical method go to your hardware store and get the glue (for the screw).

The negative, it will be extremely hard to remove the screw.